# Sync Chrome Bookmarks to Safari (or iPhone) w/o XMarks

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, google-chrome, iphone, safari, bookmarks

I'm trying to find a way to sync bookmarks (one way from Chrome to Safari) ultimately so I can sync them to the iPhone but continue to use Chrome as my fulltime desktop browser.

Alternatively, I would be open to a solution where I can view my Chrome bookmarks in a mobile webpage on my iPhone.

I realize a solution exists in [Xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com/). I would just like to see if it's possible to avoid using it.

Answer (score 2):

> Alternatively, I would be open to a solution where I can view my Chrome bookmarks in a mobile webpage on my iPhone

They're [available](https://docs.google.com/?pli=1&authuser=0#folders/ChromiumSync.0.0DYPClhGh_TCfcGdvb2dsZV9jaHJvbWVfYm9va21hcmtz) on Google Docs.

Comment: Oh my gosh so cool! I had no idea. This will work good enough though oddly those bookmarks don't seem to show up on the mobile docs site on my iPhone.

Comment: @Travis just click on the Desktop link at the footer and you'll be able to access them.

Comment: this no longer works as your google chrome bookmarks do not sync with google docs anymore